# Import data generated by JavaScript into R or Stata

Tags: r, json, stata, google-earth-engine

I have been given a csv file that looks like this:

```
id,v2,class
1,1,"{2=22.7, 0=4.8, 3=321}"
2,1,"{2=929.5, 1=11.2, 3=1229.8}"
3,2,"{2=50.9, 1=28.8}"
```

I need to make this tabular -- more specifically, import this into an `R` data frame or `Stata`. At the end of the day, I want to have a table that looks like this:

```
id  v2  class_0 class_1 class_2 class_3
1   1   4.8     0       22.7    321
2   1   0       11.2    929.5   1229.8
3   2   0       28.8    50.9    0
```

The problematic "column" (*class*) has data on what should become 4 columns in a table. Note, however, that values 0 do not show in the original file.

### Background

This file was generated in Google Earth Engine, which uses JavaScript. Save for the fact that it is indeed a comma-separated values file, the problematic "column" (*class*) looks like a JSON object to me (which makes sense, since the file was generated by JavaScript). However, it is clear that this is not a JSON file.

Given that, in `R`, I tried to interpret the culprit column as JSON, and did following:

```
library("rjson")
df = read.csv(csv_file)
json_data = fromJSON(paste(df$waterClass, collapse=""))
> Error in fromJSON(paste(df$waterClass, collapse = "")) :
  unexpected character "1"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value
```

No luck.

I guess I could a more brute-force approach, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert each row to a DCF format record and then read it in using `read.dcf`.  First read it into `DF0` and then reform each line into a DCF formatted record giving `v`.  Then read it using `read.dcf`, rerrange the columns and convert them to numeric giving a numeric matrix.  Finally replace NAs with 0.  No packages are used.

```
DF0 <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
v <- with(DF0, paste0("\nid:", id, "\nv2:", v2, chartr("{}=,", "\n :\n", class)))
v <- gsub(" ", "", v)
m <- read.dcf(textConnection(v))
nms <- c("id", "v2", sort(setdiff(colnames(m), c("id", "v2"))))
mm <- apply(m[, nms], 2, as.numeric)
mm[is.na(mm)] <- 0
mm
```

giving this numeric matrix:

```
     id v2   0    1     2      3
[1,]  1  1 4.8  0.0  22.7  321.0
[2,]  2  1 0.0 11.2 929.5 1229.8
[3,]  3  2 0.0 28.8  50.9    0.0
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- 'id,v2,class
1,1,"{2=22.7, 0=4.8, 3=321}"
2,1,"{2=929.5, 1=11.2, 3=1229.8}"
3,2,"{2=50.9, 1=28.8}"'
```

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv('id,v2,class
1,1,"{2=22.7, 0=4.8, 3=321}"
2,1,"{2=929.5, 1=11.2, 3=1229.8}"
3,2,"{2=50.9, 1=28.8}"')

df_clean <- df %>% 
    separate_rows(class, sep = ',') %>%    # separate dict elements
    separate(class, c('key', 'value'), sep = '=') %>%    # split key-value pairs
    mutate(key = paste0('class_', parse_number(key)),    # clean up
           value = parse_number(value)) %>% 
    spread(key, value, fill = 0)    # spread back to wide form

df_clean
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>      id    v2 class_0 class_1 class_2 class_3
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     4.8     0      22.7    321 
#> 2     2     1     0      11.2   930.    1230.
#> 3     3     2     0      28.8    50.9      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fudge it a bit to add some quotes and then *jsonlite* should be able to take care of it:

```
library(jsonlite)
cbind(
  dat[c("id","v2")],
  stream_in(textConnection(
    gsub("(\\s+|\\{)(.+?)=(.+?)(,|})", '\\1"\\2":\\3\\4', dat$class))
  )
)
# Imported 3 records. Simplifying...
#  id v2     2    0      3    1
#1  1  1  22.7  4.8    321 <NA>
#2  2  1 929.5 <NA> 1229.8 11.2
#3  3  2  50.9 <NA>   <NA> 28.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Stata solution with the example data as `data.csv`:

```
import delimited using data.csv, clear
split class, parse(,) 
drop class 
reshape long class, i(id) j(which) 
replace class = subinstr(class, "{", "", .) 
replace class = subinstr(class, "}", "", .) 
split class, parse("=") destring 
drop class which 
rename (class?) (which class_) 
replace class_ = 0 if missing(class_) 
drop if missing(which) 
reshape wide class_, i(id) j(which) 
mvencode class_*, mv(0) 

list

     +-------------------------------------------------+
     | id   class_0   class_1   class_2   class_3   v2 |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1       4.8         0      22.7       321    1 |
  2. |  2         0      11.2     929.5    1229.8    1 |
  3. |  3         0      28.8      50.9         0    2 |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
```